# CMake for Code::Blocks -- how to NOT get a Makefile

Tags: cmake, mingw, codeblocks, cortex-m

Here is my setup:
Windows 7 x64, MingW, Msys, CMake, Freescale Kinetis SDK, Code::Blocks

I'm trying to get the project settings established by CMake into a proper Code::Blocks project.  When I modify the provided `build_debug.bat` file with `-G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles"`, it indeed produces a `.cbp` file, as well as the normal `Makefile` (and it builds the project).  However when I open this `.cbp` file in Code::Blocks, it basically just points to the `Makefile`, and building the project just runs `make` on the `Makefile`.

If I deselect "This is a custom Makefile" from Project Options, and add a source file to the project tree like a normal IDE, it doesn't get built correctly, ie the include files, libraries, linker stuff, compile options, etc., are not imported into the project itself.  It seems the project is basically just a holder for the Makefile, so there is not much benefit to this as an IDE.

Of course if I add the source file to the original `CMakeLists.txt` which is part of the distribution, and rerun cmake (via the build_debug.bat file), then it works fine.

So is there any way to get a "real" IDE configuration out of CMake?  I'm guessing the answer is No, since a "real" IDE configuration is a static thing, and a Makefile is a general (Turing complete) program, so there is no way in general to create this automatically, although I suspect for 99% of cases you're just specifying include directories, lib files, and compiler options, so no general programmability is truly needed.

I can probably try to figure out where the deeply obscured gcc calls are getting their include files from, what libs are being linked in, and what compile options are being used, and add all that stuff manually into a native Code::Blocks project, but this seems to defeat the purpose of having this already done for me by the package providers, and gets very tedious when building for a different CPU or development board.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "Real configuration" **is** a `CMakeLists.txt`, and you **need** to modify CMakeLists when you editing project configuration. Both makefiles and IDE settings generated by CMake are temporary and you should not edit them.
2. Some IDEs are able to manage project configuration directly in the `CMakeLists.txt`